# $\frac{d \lambda}{d \varphi}= \tan\beta\sec\varphi$ What is : $\lambda(\varphi)=?; \varphi(\lambda)=?$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

$$\frac{d \lambda}{d \varphi}= \tan\beta\sec\varphi$$

What is:

$$\lambda(\varphi)=?; \varphi(\lambda)=?$$

$\beta-const.$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line

This is from the mathematical definition of Rhumb lines section of this article, but I do not know where this comes from and how it is calculated. I would very much appreciate a step by step solution. Not both of these if it's a problem but just one. To see how it's done, from start to finish.

Comment: Look at my answer to a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1112913/59379). In that answer, I use $\theta$ and $\phi$ to denote longitudes and latitudes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known that
$$\int \sec x dx = \ln |\sec x + \tan x | + c$$

Now let
$$y= \ln (\sec x + \tan x )$$

From which
\begin{align}
e^y &= \sec x + \tan x \\
\implies \sinh y &=\frac{1}{2}(e^y-e^{-y}) \\
                 &= \tan x
\end{align}
Thus
$$\cosh y =\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 y}=\sec x$$

And therefore
$$\tanh y = \sin x$$

Thus
\begin{align}
  \int \sec x dx & = y
    =\tanh^{-1}\left(\sin x \right)
    =\sinh^{-1}\! \left(\tan x \right)   
    =\cosh^{-1}\! \left(\sec x \right).
\end{align}
Which provides the desired result in your link.